# Same string in PHP giving 2 different outputs when echoed to screen when using bitwise functions

Tags: php, function, variables, bitwise-xor

Currently, I am working with XOR bitwise function in PHP and am trying to determine the reason why I am not getting my expected output. I hard coded the values and found that when calling a function that contains the echo I get only numbers in my string. But if I echo a variable containing the same data I get the expected output.

```
<?php
    include "bitwise.php";
    echo $t . "<br>";
    temp("1234");   
?>
```

I am calling the below code from the above code.

```
$t = (((((("1324" ^ $h1) . "1234") ^ $h2) . ("1324" ^ $h1)) ^ $h3) . ((("1324" ^ $h1) . "1234") ^ $h2) ^ $h5);

function temp($str)
{
    $test = (((((("1324" ^ $h1) . "1234") ^ $h2) . ("1324" ^ $h1)) ^ $h3) . ((("1324" ^ $h1) . "1234") ^ $h2) ^ $h5);
    echo $test;

    return $test;
}
```

The `$h#` are strings contain a jumble of characters that remain constant for both attempts. The outputs are:

```
$t
Le7KXh}*J;GKUqzo9

$test
9223372036854775807
```

I would like to know why I am getting only numbers in the second example

Comment: You're not using the `$str` argument, and `$h1`, `$h2`, etc. are undefined within the scope of the `temp` function.

Comment: [The PHP manual on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the variables `h1` to `h5` are defined out of the function scope, they are interpreted as a string and not as their values.

Try adding the following string to your function:

```
global $h1, $h2, $h3, $h4, $h5;
```

And it should work.
Look at this code for reference: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a801c15422b69cc2d7ba067e70a5077abe03c1a9